# SQL - Select Distinct filtering

Tags: sql

I need to find every entry in a table that does NOT contain a specific value.  I'm writing a report that will pull every distinct workstation name that does NOT have a specific software ID installed.  The table I'm pulling from has an entry for every software installed on every machine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ws_name

FROM table

WHERE software_id 123 does not exist
```

I don't know what code to replace the "does not exist" part of the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to exclude `ws_name`s that have `software_id = 123` in **any of the rows**. If this is correct, you'd need a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ws_name
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable b
                   WHERE  a.ws_name = b.ws_name AND b.software_id = 123)
```

Or use the `in` operator with a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ws_name
FROM   mytable
WHERE  ws_name NOT IN (SELECT ws_name
                       FROM   mytable
                       WHERE  software_id = 123)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The sub query using NOT EXISTS is what I needed.  First time asking a question, I'll be more detailed in my questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Putting more about the table schemas (and the DBMS you use) coule be useful to provide better answers. Still with what you have I think you could use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ws_name
FROM table
WHERE ws_name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ws_name 
                      FROM table
                      WHERE software_id = 123)
```